# A fatal error in PDO that doesn't make sense?

Tags: sqlite, pdo

When I execute this method, the database returns the following error:
1. There's nothing wrong with the database, checked all the column names and they match. Also the code is syntactically correct. I have another method with the same implementation, only the table and column names are different.

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\timetable-generator-v2\inout.php on line 173


$db = new Database();
$db->insertRule("something", NULL, NULL);


class Database{
    private $conn;
    function __construct() {
        try {
            $this->conn = new PDO("sqlite:" . DATABASE);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage() . " - failed on: Database->__construct()";
            die();
        }

    }
    function insertRule($ruleName, $isNot, $isInverse){
        $ruleId = "ru1";//$this->generateId(RULE);
        try {
            $q = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO Rule(ruleId, ruleName, not, inverse) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)");
            $q->execute(array($ruleId, $ruleName, $isNot, $isInverse));
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage() . " - failed on: Database->insertRule()";
            die();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NOT` is a kewyword.
Use `"not"` to use it as a column name.

Answer (score 0):

a proper code to make yourself aware of the errors

```
class Database{
    private $conn;
    function __construct() {
        $opt = array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $this->conn = new PDO("sqlite:" . DATABASE,NULL,NULL,$opt);
    }
    function insertRule($ruleName, $isNot, $isInverse){
        $ruleId = "ru1";//$this->generateId(RULE);
        $q = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO Rule(`ruleId`, `ruleName`, `not`, `inverse`) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)");
        $q->execute(array($ruleId, $ruleName, $isNot, $isInverse));
    }
}
```

though whatever particular insertRule shoudn't be in the Database class